# How to verify string type geographic coordinates are in the correct format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have :

```
coordinates = '50.0572, 1.20575'
```

coordinates is string type.

50.0572 is latitude
1.2057 is longitude

I would like to find the simplest solution to verify that coordinates is in the format of type: XX.XX, XX.XX

Example : if coordinates = '120, 1.20' => False => bad format (error on 120)

Thank you.

Comment: I would like to check the string with a regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first `.split(',')` then check `.isdigit()` if get `True` you have `int` number and you find `bad format`.

try this:

```
>>> coordinates = '120, 1.20'
>>> [cor.isdigit() for cor in coordinates.split(',')]
[True, False]

>>> coordinates = '50.0572, 1.20575'
>>> if not any(cor.isdigit() for cor in coordinates.split(',')):
...    print("we don't have bad format")

we don't have bad format
```

If you want to use `regex` you can use `re.compile()` then use `match` like below:

```
>>> import re
>>> flt_num = re.compile(r'\d+.\d+')

>>> coordinates = '120, 1.20'
>>> for cor in coordinates.split(','):
...    if flt_num.match(cor):
...        print(f'{cor} has bad format')

120 has bad format
```

Comment: I would like to check  the format with a regex